# Report rsExecutionNotFound when exporting to other formats

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I am using CRM 4.0 SSRS. I can display reports which take a long time. When a report displays I can export to Excel, XML or another file type within in 10 minutes. But after exactly 10 minutes, I cannot export reports to Excel or other formats.

Report message is :

> The report execution ifjzab55k5icxl4510oyfsmt has expired or cannot be found. (rsExecutionNotFound)

Report Server Log Text:

> ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: , An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.;
>   session!ReportServer_0-10!17c8!05/09/2013-16:03:14:: e ERROR: Error in getting session data: Expired Session: qkmiqv455sdu5wyc2sa23az1
>   session!ReportServer_0-10!17c8!05/09/2013-16:03:14:: i INFO: LoadSnapshot: Item with session: qkmiqv455sdu5wyc2sa23az1, reportPath: , userName: VRVENDING\crm.service not found in the database
>   library!ReportServer_0-10!17c8!05/09/2013-16:03:14:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ExecutionNotFoundException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ExecutionNotFoundException: The report execution qkmiqv455sdu5wyc2sa23az1 has expired or cannot be found"

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the session that SSRS was using to store your reports data has expired, releasing the cached data; so when you attempt to export there's nothing there *to* export.  Simply clicking "View Report" again should rebuild that cache, and allow you to export, however I can understand that not being the ideal user experience.

2 things I'd suggest trying:

1. Increase the session timeout for SSRS.
2. In the web.config, find the "httpRuntime" element, and add a "RequestLength" property to it, set that value to something absurdly high, like 100000, and see if that helps.  (do this in both the reportserver and reportmanager web.configs)

Given the error message, I doubt that the 2nd one is your issue, but still may be worth checking out, as I've seen similar behavior that was fixed with that (albeit with a much different error message).

You could also try tinkering with the reports snapshot settings, however the amount of overhead that introduce on your server may outweigh the benefits of letting people export their report...